# trying to use blockchain.info donate button

Tags: api, blockchain.info

I am trying to put a donation button on a web page.  I copied and pasted the code obtained by clicking the `Donation Button` on this page: https://blockchain.info/address/1BgggUDmCf18DTvNQvkSEyNEmofojaTeek

The resulting page is: https://tiferesyisroel.org/donate-bitcoin.html

However, when I try to test this in Firefox by clicking on the `Dontate` image, the image simply disappears.  When I investigate in Firebug I see that when I click, the browser is getting a 404 when it tries to do a GET from blockchain.info.

When I test the page in Chrome I get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, I get the same problem. Maybe ask the blockchain guys why `https://blockchain.info/receive` 404's?

Comment: I'm trying to use this donation button too. I've just submitted a request to the blockchain.info guys, and linked them to this question as well.